# Inter-aggregate communication

Tags: event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I currently have a single event stream per aggregate root and twoaggregate roots, `Room` and `RoomType`.

The behavior of a `Room` depends on what `RoomType` it is. In order to separate both aggregates, The `RoomType` is just represented as a roomTypeId in the `Room` aggregate. A change of `RoomType` is represented by a `RoomTypeChanged` event.

The `RoomTypes` can be managed separately and need to be in a different aggregate.

Now consider the following use case:

When a user invalidates a `RoomType`, all `Rooms` that have that `Roomtype` should switch to a fallback `RoomType`.

I have thought of several approaches, but all of them seem to be problematic:

1. Have an event listener listen for a `RoomTypeInvalidated`-event, and send a `SwitchToFallbackRoomType` on all `Room`-aggregates that have that `Roomtype`. 
   How would I do this though? There's no way to know which aggregates have that `Roomtype` unless I access my readmodel, which seems incorrect.
   Even if I were to load all aggregates, there's no way to load only the aggregates of that type as I can't load a subset of all streams (using geteventstore).
2. When reapplying the `RoomTypeChanged`-events to the `Room` aggregate, instead of just applying it, do a check to see whether that `RoomType` still exists, but then again, how would I know which `RoomTypes` exist (I'd be in the same situation as 1, but inverted)? Also, it seems wrong to put in logic on reapplying events, they should just represent state changes I think.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

We are working with the same issue, also rooms and roomtypes. The solution you are having problems reaching is probably mapped from the relational where this is a non issue. It's hard and confusing to think start thinking behavioral in an otherwise very data-driven field.
I think the to solve the problem you have to challenge the proposed solution.

When re-thinking it, we ended up with aggregates like RoomAssignment and RoomAllocationSchedule, and discovered that RoomType is mostly used to communicate room-features to external channels / OTA.

Modelling the behavior we need really helps (since the consistency bounderies starts to make sense), instead of modelling data and trying to enforce relational consistent behavior on it...

When we really need consistency across aggregates, we model a process-manager/saga that in itself is transactionally consistent, and message the aggregates. As such, we have a "RoomAssignmentDirector" aggregate, that makes sure that a room is allocated for a roomstay before it is assigned to the roomstay etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a process manager per roomtype and have the list of rooms as a property of the process manager?
Querying the read model from a service or from the command handler will not guarantee a consistent framework. What if a room was assigned to the invalidated room type but the read model wasn't updated yet? ( that's sort of the scenario I'm facing)

Comment: The issue with the process manager per roomtype is how is it's state updated. If you update it in the same command that creates a room, you now need transactions to ensure that the DB state remains consistent (you have 2 write operations: the room and the manager). If on the other hand you update the process manager from an event handler, then you have a different version of the same problem OP mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Solving this problem by making sure that data is completely consistent every time is working against the design. Event Sourcing presumes the system is **eventually consistent** so having inconsistencies at the read model is normal and expected.

The best way to solve this would be to query your read model for all rooms with the new invalidated TypeId (your solution 1). After updating all those rooms, there is a possibility that there are a few stragglers that are were not updated, so you re-run the event handler a few moment later (let's say a minute).

At that point (assuming that your Commands checks the validity of the room type at Room creation) it is impossible for new rooms to be created with the old room-type and the read model for the stragglers should have already stabilized. So re-running the code will update everything remaining.

Comment: Eventual consistency is fine, but inconsistency is not. How do you know how long to wait? 1 second, 1 minute or a day? If you don't wait long enough, your data is inconsistent (not just your read-model).

Comment: Took long to answer this but here goes. Eventual consistency by definition implies a system that tolerates an inconsistent state. If you need full 100% all time consistency, go with ACID. To solve the "how long" problem you execute your check several times until data stabilizes. For example run it every minute until there are no more rooms to update. And then, you can re-run it again in an hour. Also, to avoid contamination, you can do an extra check when accesing that property in another command, to make sure you are not using stale data.

Comment: The problem is that you don't know when there are no more rooms to update, so you'd have to keep running it forever. That's exaggerated, but the point still stands, how long do you keep rerunning it? You're trying to solve an consistency problem by reading from an eventual consistent source.

Comment: I understand it might sound a bit insane, but that's the way Eventually consistent systems work. If you stop adding data to the system and keep running the task, at some point, no old data will remain and the system will become consistent. Of course, if you keep running operations, the system will never fully stabilize since while old operations become stable, new ones are still unknown.